# Metaplex Cache file disappeared

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

I made the metaplex collection upload yesterday everything went well.
Managed to air drop a certain amount, verify the collection. Everything worked perfectly.

Today, I want to update the time of the public mint but it seems that the cache file is now missing. it's not hidden, yesterday it was here in plain site. This is the command I used

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKsij.png)

This is the new config I want to update
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELPLt.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you are in the same location as you used yesterday.

Search for .cache folders anywhere on your drive.

If you really cannot find the cache file anymore

1. check what’s wrong with your device
2. create a new cache file. The Uris do not have to be added. (Items Array can empty). UUID consists of the first characters of the candy machine address. Please refer to a cache file of a different candy machine or quickly create one in devnet and use it as basis.

For future users: maybe [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/issues/1394#issuecomment-1005134452) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer on here: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/issues/1394

You can re-create the file by using these information:

```
{
  "program": {
    "uuid": "",
    "candyMachine": "xxxxx"
  },
  "items": {},
  "env":"mainnet-beta",
  "cacheName":"mainnet",
  "startDate":"61c65f00"
}
```

`UUID` is the 6 first letter of the candy machine